# Pandas datetime

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm looking to get a list of the number of students who cancelled withing a week of joining. So far, I've converted a csv file's 'join_date' & 'cancel_date' column from string to date using pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
def parse_date(date):
    if date == '':
        return None
    else: 
        return pd.to_datetime(date)

for enrollment in enrollments:

    enrollment['cancel_date'] = parse_date(enrollment['cancel_date'])
    enrollment['join_date'] = parse_date(enrollment['join_date'])
```

this is the code i've come up with so far

```
test = []

stuffed = (enrollments['cancel_date'].dt.days - enrollments['join_date'].dt.days)

for i in stuffed:
    if i.days < 7:
        test.apppend(i)
```

and it gives the following error:

> TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: What line in the code gives you the error? Also, reading the "TypeError", it seems to me that your indices are of type string. Convert the 'list indices' to integers `int(<result here>)`

Comment: the error if from the subraction line:
stuffed = (enrollments['join_date'].dt.days - enrollments['cancel_date'].dt.days)

Comment: is `enrollments['john_date'].dt.days` returning a string or an integer? If both of the `.dt.days` are giving back a string: try `stuffed = int(enrollments['join_date'].dt.days) - int(enrollments['cancel_date'].dt.days)`

Comment: it's running from a string. cause even when i run 
enrollments['join_date'] 
i get the same error. i've parsed both 'join' & cancel dates as dates so im not sure why im getting a str error